# Mule ESB and MongoDB Connector- Collection data not being stored when calling insert-object-from-map

Tags: mule

I am trying to store a JSON document(and a few other attributes) in a MongoDB Collection. I believe I am not using the insert-object-from-map operation on the MongoDB Connector correctly.

I am creating a Map from the JSON document and passing that into the connector in hopes that it will create my collection. I verified that my Groovy code is properly creating the Map. The collection is being created, however there are no records in the collection. It seems that the MongoDB Connector is not getting the Map. Am I way off here? Is there a better way to create a record in a collection with the connector?

Here is my flow:

```
<flow name="post:/account:googleAccount-config" doc:name="post:/account:googleAccount-config" processingStrategy="asynchronous">
    <object-to-string-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <scripting:transformer doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy" file="src/main/groovy/jsonAccountToMap.groovy"/>
    </scripting:transformer>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <mongo:insert-object-from-map config-ref="Mongo_DB_Google_Account" collection="accounts" doc:name="Mongo DB" writeConcern="NORMAL">
        <mongo:element-attributes ref="#[payload]"/>           
    </mongo:insert-object-from-map>
</flow>
```

I also added a user to my database and updated the MongoDB Connector config to use that it, and still no data is being stored.

Thanks!
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Your Mongo insert should work correctly with correct payload. If you put `<set-payload value="#[['testkey':'testval']]"/>` before the Mongo component, you shoud get an entry with 'testkey':'testval' to your collection. Try logging your Map with `<logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>` instead of the generic logger you have now.

Comment: Hi Anton, I added <set-payload value="#[['testkey':'testval']]"/> and still nothing was stored in Mongo. I even updated the connector config  and tried to hardcode a value and it still didn't work. I am going to investigate MongoDB itself. I installed a default instance. Maybe there is something going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, everything was working all along. I was looking in the wrong collection in the MongoDB console.

It appears that the connector will add data to a Collection in MongoDB using both authenticated and unauthenticated calls.

Anton, thanks for the response!

Nathan